# Issue configuring an array dynamicaly

Tags: php, associative-array

i have a script but before that i want to explain u something

i an calling a function

```
$data['cat'] = $this->autoload_model->getTree(0,'td_category');
$data['cat'] = $this->autoload_model->getTree(0,'td_division');
```

so in the below function

```
$table = td_category
                         $table = td_division


public function getTree($pid,$table)
    {
        $table_data=explode("_",$table);
        //$table_data[1] will read category for td_category, division for td_division;
        global $sp;
        static $arr = array(
               'category_id' => array(),
               'category_title' => array()
            );
    }
```

now if i replace this two lines

```
'category_id' => array(),
    'category_title' => array()
```

by

```
$table_data[1].'_id' => array(),
    $table_data[1].'_title' => array()
```

then i am getting error due to the static nature of the array,
but if i delete the static keyword, then it doesnt show any error

how can i keep the static keywod and also get the associative fields dynamicaly base on the $table sent

Comment: no, he don't need variable vars here. he want to name the index of the subarray dynamically. this should be the correct way.

Comment: Your array is either `static` or it isn't. Yours isn't, so don't use `static` or don't use dynamic keys during its initialization.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure very much but you can try following

```
static $arr = array();

$arr[$table_data[1].'_id'] = array();
$arr[$table_data[1].'_title'] = array();
```

Answer (score -2):

You mean something like this?

```
${$table_data[1]."_title"} => array();
```